# Getting NULL not allowed error for Primary Key column even when not inserting a null value

Tags: java, sql, h2

I noticed that when I try to insert a record into a Primary Key column, I'm getting a `NULL not allowed for column` error, even if the value I'm trying to enter for that column is not null.  Does anyone know why this would happen!?  My PreparedStatement.toString() is below along with the stack trace.  Thank you very much for any help!

```
PreparedStatement = 'prep0: MERGE INTO results (rank,lastname,firstname,country,time) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?); {1: '1', 2: 'smith', 3: 'john', 4: 'USA', 5: '2:30'}'...
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "FIRSTNAME"; SQL statement:
MERGE INTO results (rank,lastname,firstname,country,time) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?); [23502-193]`

    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:311)
    at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:784)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Merge.merge(Merge.java:157)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Merge.update(Merge.java:106)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:98)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:201)
    at Table.merge(Table.java:272)
    at CSV.writeToDatabase(CSV.java:643)
    at CLI.combineData(CLI.java:152)
    at CLI.run(CLI.java:48)
    at CLI.main(CLI.java:163)`
```

here is the method that creates the query:

```
    void merge( Map<String,Object> values ) throws SQLException
    {
        if ( values.isEmpty() )
        {
            System.out.println("No data in values map..."); 
            return;
        }
        query = new StringBuilder("MERGE INTO " + name + " (");

        List<String> attrs = new ArrayList<>(values.keySet());

        for ( int a=0; a < attrs.size(); a++ ) 
        {
            query.append( a > 0 ? "," : "" ).append( attrs.get(a).toLowerCase() ); 
        }
        query.append(") VALUES (");

        for ( int a=0; a < attrs.size(); a++ )
        {
            query.append( a > 0 ? ",?" : "?" );
        }
        query.append(");");

        PreparedStatement ps = db.conn.prepareStatement(query.toString());

        for ( int v=0; v < attrs.size(); v++ )
        {
            Object value = values.get(attrs.get(v));

            if ( value == null )
            {
                ps.setString(v+1, null);
            }
            else if ( value instanceof String || value instanceof Date)
            {
                ps.setString(v+1, value.toString() );
            }
            else if ( value instanceof Integer )
            {
                ps.setInt(v+1, (Integer) value);
            }
            else if ( value instanceof Double )
            {
                ps.setDouble(v+1, (Double) value);
            }
            else 
            {
                ps.setString(v+1, null);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("PreparedStatement = '" + ps.toString() + "'...");
        ps.execute();
    }
```

Comment: What does the structure of the table look like?

Comment: Can you please show us the code that generates the statement and executes it ?

Comment: lastName and firstName are primary keys

Comment: 1.try with insert instead of merge and see if work. 2. as i see from h2 doc in merge is better to specify also primary key, compound here if understand. Me not working with h2 but as i see the query should be something : merge into results (...) key (firstname,lastname) values.... 3.also try to run original merge query as it is but connect in an old way with a browser (even an ide: eclipse)

Comment: Good thought, I did try that already and I'm getting the same error...